# How do I edit array proreprty via built-in @Html.EditorFor(..)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I got `ProductModel` with property `public ProductCategoryModel Category { get; set; }`. The `ProductCategoryModel` is obviously set of categories that gonna be added or removed dynamically. So at the time of creation/edtition of `ProductModel` I need a 1-value-onle drop-down list with existing categories. Can I use `@Html.EditorFor(...)` for this purpose somehow?

The solutions which I proceed on now is

```
@Html.DropDownList(
            "CategoryTitle",
            SelectListGenerator.GenerateFrom(categoires, i => i.Title, i => i.Title),
            new { htmlAttributes = new {
                @class = "form-control",
                @data_val = "true",
                @data_val_required = "Не выбрана категория!",
                @id = "CategoryTitle",
                @name = "CategoryTitle"
            } })
```

Because it returns not the `ProductCategoryModel` object, but just a string - name of it, I forced to do extra work in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateProduct_ViewModel vm)
    {
        vm.ProductModel.Category = _productCategoryEntities.ByName(vm.CategoryTitle);
        ValidateModel(vm);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {               
            _productEntities.Products.Add(vm.ProductModel);
            _productEntities.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return View(vm);
    }
```

This code looks kind of messy and deffiecient.

So, once again, at the time of creation of new `ProductModel` I need a drop-down list, where one can select existing category rather than form for creating a new one (this is default for `@Html.EditorFor(...)`). And I want to recieve an `ProductModel` object into my `Create(...)` method so it looks like `Create(ProductModel model)` within assigned `Category` property thus avoiding this `vm.ProductModel.Category = _productCategoryEntities.ByName(vm.CategoryTitle);`.

Comment: Why not use a Category dropdown ? You can do `multiple` selection if needed

Comment: @Shyju Because it does not associates Category property properly. It is always null. Moreover, if I mark it as [Required], it throws an Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EditorFor` is a templated helper. It picks which template to use based on the property type, `DataType` annotation, etc. Because `CategoryTitle` is a just a string, you get a standard textbox.

`DropDownListFor` is more appropriate here, since you need that control explicitly. If the posted value is always null, that means you're not binding it properly. It should be tied to a property on your view model and the value you post should be the same type (or coerce-able to that type). For example, the posted value of a select element will always be a string, but if it's something like "1", the modelbinder is intelligent enough to bind that to an int property. However, if the posted value was something like "true" and you attempted to bind that to an int, it would not bind, because "true" is not coerce-able to an int. That's a contrived example, but it's merely to illustrate the point.

Having to lookup up the category by the posted value is unavoidable. Again, the posted value will be a string. There is no way to post an entire category object from a select element. Therefore, the best you can do is use the posted value to lookup the category object, and then associate that with the category property.